# Create a two separate arrays from existing array in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have a `array of n` elements say

```
snaps = ["s-1","s-2","s-3","s-4",..."s-n-2","s-n-1","s-n"]
```

now I want to create two diff array such that one array contains last 5 elements and another contains remaining elements.For example

```
snap1 = ["s-1","s-2","s-3","s-4",...]
snap2 = ["s-n-5","s-n-3","s-n-2","s-n-1","s-n"]
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
snap2 = snaps[-5, 5]
```

Or

```
snap2 = snaps.last(5) # As suggested my BroiSatse
```

will give you an array with the last 5 elements

For the remaining, you can do

```
snap1 = snaps[0..-6]
```

Comment: You can use `.last(5)` instead. Also note, that if array has repetitions, subtraction will remove all repeated elements.

Comment: `snap1 = snaps - snap2` will likely yield wrong results in the case `snaps` contains duplicate entries.

Answer (score 5):

```
snap1 = snaps.dup
snap2 = snap1.pop(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) to create the two arrays:

```
snaps = ["s-1","s-2","s-3","s-4","s-n-5","s-n-3","s-n-2","s-n-1","s-n"] 

snap2 = snaps.slice!(-5..-1)
# => ["s-n-5", "s-n-3", "s-n-2", "s-n-1", "s-n"] 

snaps
# => ["s-1", "s-2", "s-3", "s-4"]
```